# Limit a query inside a JOIN?

Tags: mysql

I have a query which pulls out all articles and their categories (that matches the current category).

I want it to fetch only 5 articles per category. how can i do it?

the query:

```
 SELECT a.* FROM
                    Articles   a
                    LEFT JOIN Articles_category b
                    ON a.id=b.article_id
                    LEFT JOIN Categories c
                    ON c.id = b.category_id
                    LEFT JOIN Articles_category ac1
                    ON ac1.main = 1 AND a.id = ac1.article_id AND ac1.position > 0
                    WHERE c.id = '14' 
                    ORDER BY b.main DESC
```

I want it to select only 5 articles tops for each category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with that query. You would have to loop a similar query to that, based on the category id. You could do it in a stored procedure, or loop the query repeatedly in code.

Comment: It looks like your current code is doing it already, for an individual category. You would need to put "LIMIT 5" at the end to return only the last 5 rows. That would return the first 5 of that category that match, you would need to then loop through the categories in PHP. I'm not familiar with with syntax you would need for a stored procedure, but I would believe it would be SELECT on the categories table, then multiple runs of that statement.